# Struggling to pass ansible variable in python script

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-2.x

recently i started to look up Ansible to automate server provisioning, but i cant seem to import a specific variable in my yml file to my .py script for it to be used. Example of what im looking for:

```
.yml
var:
server_name: ml-apitest-t1
```

then import that variable `server_name` to my variable in python, so it would kinda look like this:

```
self.server_name = .yml server_name
```

Answer (score 1):

if your `.yml.` file looks somewhat like this:

```
- server:
    var:
    server_name: ml-apitest-t1
```

then you should use `PyYaml`, try this

```py
import yaml
try:
    from yaml import CLoader as Loader, CDumper as Dumper
except ImportError:
    from yaml import Loader, Dumper

with open('test.yml', 'r') as f:
    cont = yaml.load(f.read(), Loader=Loader)

print (cont)
```

in the case of my example it would output this

```
[{'server': {'var': None, 'server_name': 'ml-apitest-t1'}}]
```

to get the `server_name` from my test `.yml` file i would need to do this, but i your case it would look different because your `.yml` file structure is different

```py
import yaml
try:
    from yaml import CLoader as Loader, CDumper as Dumper
except ImportError:
    from yaml import Loader, Dumper

with open('test.yml', 'r') as f:
    cont = yaml.load(f.read(), Loader=Loader)

print (cont[0]['server']['server_name'])
```

and this is the output

```
ml-apitest-t1
```

Also here is the `PyYaml` [documentation](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but how would i go about returning a value that has been processed in a running ansible playbook?

Comment: put `cont[0]['server']['server_name']` in a var and use it as you wish

Answer (score 1):

You could assign these variables as environment variable using ansible task, then access it through python.
To set environment variable in ansible:

```
- hosts: dev
  tasks:
    - name: Set server_name
      environment:
        SERVER_NAME: server_name
```

To access environment variable in python, use something like this:

```
import os
self.server_name = os.environ['SERVER_NAME']
```

Remember that the ENV above are only temporary in play level, so your python script must be called in the same play.